# If water vapour is a green house gas , then how is using hydrogen fuel cell stopping global warming?

Tags: hydrogen, renewable-energy

Hydrogen fuel cells produce water vapour then aren't they also contributing towards global warming ?

Answer (score 4):

Water vapour can condense out of the atmopshere. CO2 can't but can cause a temperature increase that causes even more water vapour to enter the atmosphere in a positive feedback loop.